# Unrecognized selector sent using UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, unrecognized-selector

I want to add a `UISegmentedControl` to a view controller and this is the corresponding code:

```
import UIKit

class QuantityNoImageViewController: UIViewController {
    var food: Food!

    @IBOutlet weak var foodName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var message1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var message2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var message3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func segmentControlPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
      switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
      case 0: print("one");
      case 1: print("two");
      case 2: print("three")
      default: break;
      }
    }
```

`@IBOutlet segmentControl` as well as `@IBAction segmentControlPressed` are properly set.

When I run the app, all goes nicely until I press a segment which produces:

```
2017-12-15 17:22:11.840952+0100 Healthier[3835:248257] -[Healthier.QuantityNoImageViewController segmentedControl1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc52e03ae00
2017-12-15 17:22:11.863471+0100 Healthier[3835:248257] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Healthier.QuantityNoImageViewController segmentedControl1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc52e03ae00'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I just cannot find any pointer that help me to solve this apparently simple bug. Could you please provide me some assistance?

Comment: Guess? You had previously declared something like `func  segmentedControl1:(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)`, no? Check on your storyboard what item it connected to it, and remove it.

Comment: `segmentedControl1` is not the same as `segmentControlPressed`.

Comment: how does your segmented control is connected from interface builder ? how does its action is connected ?

Comment: SO you've put a breakpoint in `segmentControlPressed` and hit it? So the error references `segementedControl1` but you've shown **no** code for what that is? It's rather difficult to help when you've shown incomplete code!

Answer (score 2):

You may have connected, multiple connections with this action (Exact I mean, you have copied this segment control from other screen and its previous connection is still not disconnected)

Reset/remove all IBAction connections with this segment and re-connect.

Storyboard/XIB >> View Controller >> Connection Inspector >> Reset all IBActions for segment control

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have no excuse, I appreciate and I hope to be able to help when I'll grow in experience !